# How to check if three values equal the same string

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string a = "v";
    string b = "v";
    string c = "v";
    if(a,b,c == "v"){
        //do something
    }
}
```

and when I tried to use "&&" it only checked if a,b and c were equal to eachother rather than a specific string and the comma thing worked at first but when i added more than one if statement with the commas then it stopped working

Comment: `a == "v" && b == "v" && c == "v"`?

Comment: Instead of describing the code, show the `&&` code. Do not use commas, that is not how they work.

Comment: `if ((a==b) && (b==c))`

Comment: `if(a==b && b==c && a == "v")`

Comment: Look up the "comma operator" in your C++ book, btw.

Comment: `a,b,c == "v"`  evaluates `a`, `b`, and `c == "v`,  discards the results of evaluating `a` and `b`.  So it is functionally (ignoring results of evaluating and discarding `a` and `b`) functionally equivalent to `c == v`.      To do what you want you need three comparisons that ALL need to test true, so do something like `if (a == "v" && b == a && c == a)` which will test if `a` is equivalent to `"v"` and (knowing that) then compare `b` and `c` with `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very obvious is to test that both `a` and `b` are equal *and* `b` and `c` are.

```
if (a == b && b == c) {
    ...
}
```

Less obvious is to create a set from the three strings and test that it only has size `1`.

```
std::set<std::string> s { a, b, c };

if (s.size() == 1) {
    ...
}
```

If you need to test that they all are equal *and* equal `"v"` then add `"v"` to the set.

```
std::set<std::string> s { "v", a, b, c };

if (s.size() == 1) {
    ...
}
```

As it is, your code using commas effectively ignores the values in `a` and `b` and simply considers `c` == `"v"`.

Comment: Keep in mind, `std::set` uses `std::less` and equivalence comparison instead of direct/exact equality. For a built-in type this shouldn't matter but for some UDTs it can make a difference.